# Jetson cameras with raspberry pi zero board

Tags: camera

There are some cameras defined as for Jetson nano bourd only. Like IMX219-160, IMX219-120, IMX219-200 (you could google this names).
They are with CSI interface and imx219 sensor like rpi camera v2. Looks like they could be used with respberry pi zero.

Does somebody use them with raspberry boards?

How mush fps they can provide?

I choose this camere because they have own lens holder and you can change the optic lens.

Best regards, Alex.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do specifically with the Pi.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Why it is not specifically with the Pi? I want use raspberry pi zero board with CSI-2 interface with Jetson Camera(with different lens).
I found that Jetson board could use raspberry cameras but no for vice versa.